# Combine two pivot tables SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to cross join two pivot tables.

--First Pivot table query gets columns of drug_names and produces the row value
--of the drug_id.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

Select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(drug) 
                    from _app_drugs
                    group by drug, drug_id,order_number
                    order by order_number
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select drug_id, drug
                from _app_drugs
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(drug_id)
                for drug in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'

exec sp_executesql @query;

--The second pivot table simply gets the signature_labels and displays the label name in the column and displays the label_id as the row value.

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@scols as NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

Select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(signature_label) 
                    from _app_signature_labels
                    WHERE _app_signature_labels.isactive=1
                    group by signature_label_id, signature_label,ordernumber
                    order by ordernumber
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
                select signature_label_id,signature_label
                from _app_signature_labels              
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(signature_label_id)
                for signature_label in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Now I just need to know how to combine these two pivot tables as one table... they don't have a common field and don't need one.

Can anybody help me with this one?
Thank you

Comment: You need to provide some  sample data (for each pivot table) and the desire output base on this data.

Comment: *they don't have a common field and don't need one* then why are you trying to combine them? is this for a report? (if so use sub-reports)

Comment: the other issue here is that each of those queries can have a different  number of columns, so you won't be able to use UNION ALL unless you find a way to ensure the column numbers are the same in both queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute two separate dynamic SQL statements into two global temp tables and then combine the result, like this:

```
IF object_id('tempdb..##tmpResult1') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##tmpResult1
END

IF object_id('tempdb..##tmpResult2') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##tmpResult2
END

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @cols2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

Select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(drug) 
                    from _app_drugs
                    group by drug, drug_id,order_number
                    order by order_number
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' INTO ##tmpResult1 from 
             (
                select drug_id, drug
                from _app_drugs
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(drug_id)
                for drug in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p'

exec sp_executesql @query;

--The second pivot table simply gets the signature_labels and displays the label name in the column and displays the label_id as the row value.

Select @cols2 = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(signature_label) 
                    from _app_signature_labels
                    WHERE _app_signature_labels.isactive=1
                    group by signature_label_id, signature_label,ordernumber
                    order by ordernumber
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query2 = N'SELECT ' + @cols2 + N' INTO ##tmpResult2 from 
             (
                select signature_label_id,signature_label
                from _app_signature_labels              
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(signature_label_id)
                for signature_label in (' + @cols2 + N')
            ) p'

exec sp_executesql @query2;

SELECT * FROM ##tmpResult1 t1 
  INNER JOIN ##tmpResult2 t2 ON t1.ordernumber = t2.ordernumber
```

This is also a way to address this error when doing a large PIVOT query:

> Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.